# Required Windows Phone 7 page transition/ flipping card animation for iOS

Tags: ios, windows-phone-7, animation

I want to achieve the same kind of flipping card animation for iOS application which Windows Phone 7 has.

While navigating from one page to another, it loads one by one widget with fall down from left to right position.

How to achieve the same animation for iOS?

Here is the reference: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVRT_KbYzHI

Please help out with some sample code posting or another provided link.

Comment: Thanks Jacques Cousteau for updating question. Can you please up vote the same to get some more focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve animations such as this with UIView's animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: method.  The documentation is here; search for the function name: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html

Basically you would need to place the views you want to animate inside a loop, incrementing the delay by x amount each time.

Comment: But it would not be optimized if I write code for each and every widget available on view. It should take automatically from top to bottom, left to right manner and animate and populate over view. So i am looking for such a code.

But thanks for your kind reply.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If you place the elements in an array from top to bottom, a loop such as I described would ensure they animated top-to-bottom in order.  And if you used the animation to move them right to left, that would work, right?  And if you're talking about code reuse--you could easily write a function that accepts an NSArray as a parameter and performs the operation we're discussing.  Or am I missing something?  Thanks.